# How to detect which view is being pan gestured Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a function that adds a `UIImageView` to the View Controller every second, and I'm trying to make each of these image views draggable with `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. However, I do not know how to detect which of the many image views is being dragged in my selector function. I don't want to have to use the `touchesBegan(_:with:)` function along with the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` because that could get messy. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code so far:

```
    //Function that executes every second and adds imageView
    @objc func addBalloonToDrag(){
        var myImageView=UIImageView()

        var fullWidth=Int(gameView.frame.width)
        var fullHeight=Int(gameView.frame.height)

        var widthMin=Int(gameView.frame.width*0.2)
        var widthMax=Int(gameView.frame.width*0.3)
        var randomWidth = 30
        var countdownLabelHeight=Int(countdownTimer.frame.height)

        var randomX=Int.random(in: 0...fullWidth-randomWidth)
        var randomY=Int.random(in: countdownLabelHeight...fullHeight-randomWidth)

        myImageView.frame=CGRect(x: randomX, y: randomY, width: randomWidth, height: randomWidth)

        var moodBalloonNames=["mood1","mood2","mood4","mood5"]
        var randomMoodBalloonInt=Int.random(in:0...moodBalloonNames.count)
        var randomBalloonName=moodBalloonNames[randomMoodBalloonInt]

        myImageView.image = UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: "\(randomBalloonName)").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)

        //adding pan gesture recognizer to the image view
        var panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(draggedView(_:)))
        myImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        myImageView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

        gameView.addSubview(myImageView)
    }

    @objc func draggedView(_ sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer){
        if (stopButton.titleLabel!.text == "  Pause  ")&&((totalSec != 0)||(totalMin != 0)){
            let translation = sender.translation(in: self.view)

            //How do I know which view to drag here?
            viewDrag.center = CGPoint(x: viewDrag.center.x + translation.x, y: viewDrag.center.y + translation.y)
            sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the `panGestureRecognizer.view` as an imageView and then its image property.

Comment: When I do this, I can drag the imageView that most recently appeared, but it doesn't allow me to drag the imageViews that showed up earlier.

Comment: I have one global variable called panGesture, which is a UIPanGestureRecognizer, that I'm adding to all of the image views. Do I need to make a new recognizer for each image? And if so, how do I detect the correct recognizer?

Comment: @AudreyHa You do need to create a recognizer for each image view. That way the recognizer returned in the selector function will return the relevant image view as its `view`

Comment: @Eilon Thanks! In the selector function I got the image view with "sender.view as? UIImageView" and I was able to access it.